# Unable to access Chrome Extension API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint

I am developing a chrome extensiion using react.js and I have configured webpack.js as the module bundler. I have set up the development environment to use `webpack server`, which displays the compiled output of the application on `http://localhost:8080/popup.html`
However, I was facing the following issue when I tried to access `chrome.storage.local` in my `AddFriends.jsx` file

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local')
    at eval (AddFriends.jsx:51:20)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23145:26)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24921:13)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24886:9)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24873:7)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24861:3)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27034:3)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26979:14)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js:26764:9)
    at workLoop (scheduler.development.js:266:34)
```

On searching for this issue on the internet (and on stackoverflow), I came across following solutions (in the following order)

1. Installing `npm install @types/chrome --save-dev`, produced no difference
2. Adding `webextensions: true` in `.eslintrc.js` configuration file, which i did, after setting up eslint in my extension
3. Using`/*global chrome*/` on top of my JSX file. It gave of the following error, which is understandable, since I suppose that eslint has already been configured to include `chrome`

```
ERROR in [eslint] 
/home/kabir/Desktop/Webdev projects/leetboard/src/popup/components/AddFriends.jsx
  1:10  error  'chrome' is already defined as a built-in global variable  no-redeclare
```

None of the above solutions seems to be working for me. How should I proceed now?

Here is my `.eslintrc.js` file

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "webextensions": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "env": {
                "node": true
            },
            "files": [
                ".eslintrc.{js,cjs}"
            ],
            "parserOptions": {
                "sourceType": "script"
            }
        }
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
    },
    "globals": {
        "chrome": true
    }
}
```

And here is my `webpack.config.js` file

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    popup: "./src/popup/Popup.jsx",
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/popup/popup.html",
      filename: "popup.html",
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: "public" }],
    }),
    new ESLintPlugin({
      extensions: ['js', 'jsx'],
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    static: './dist',
        client: {
            overlay: false,
        }
  },
};
```